# How do I have both a static function and class with the same name imported?

Tags: java

How can I have both a class and static function with the same name?

**main.java**

```
import static a.b.c;
import a.b.c;

public class main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    c();
    c c2 = new c();
  }
}
```

**a/b.java**

```
package a;

public class b{
  public class c{
   public c(){
     System.out.println("new c");
   }
  }
  public static void c(){
    System.out.println("c");
  }
}
```

The following currently throws an error with the following.

```
main.java:7: error: an enclosing instance that contains b.c is required
    c c2 = new c();
           ^
1 error
```

Comment: The context from your usage of "c" makes it clear to the compiler which one to use.

Comment: @Tom then why does the following work?  `import static a.b.c;import a.c;`

Comment: You have only one static "thing" named "c". No static class with the name, thus fine. And you only have one class named "c", thus "import" (without "static") is fine as well. Also mind that an import doesn't really care about duplicate names. Its like an address and it doesn't care how many people with the same name are living there. _You_ with your calls need to make sure those aren't ambiguous, for example due to context, like in the example above.

Comment: You can't. Don't choose names that collide.

Comment: @Bohemian You can, the colliding names is not a problem here.

Comment: @Lime What is the actual question here? Why this code is allowed, i.e. why the imports are fine or do you actually want to know how to fix the error message you got? (which is a completely different issue)